# Authorized endpoint returns empty 401 xml response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, response

I have a controller method which looks like this

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Employee")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ItemsDTO<Reservation>>> GetReservations([FromQuery] SliceDTO slice)
        {
            var role = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var reservations = await _reservationService.GetReservations(userName, role, slice.Page, slice.RowsPerPage, (slice.SearchTerm != null) ? slice.SearchTerm : "");
            return Ok(reservations);
        }
```

When the user is authorized it works perfectly fine. When the user is not authorized, I get a 401 response as expected, however, for some reason the content type is set to xml. This does not really break anything, but creates console errors when trying to parse an empty xml response body. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: I get a "XML Parsing Error: no root element found" in my browser console whenever my access token expires and I send a request to this endpoint.

Comment: Can you add break point in above code and see if you reach break point?

Comment: It does not get to my code, I'm using the built-in asp.net core authorization, which returns a 401 response if the access token is invalid. If I understand correctly, I need to change the content type of this response to json, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You need to add another action result to capture the not authorize users which should stop the console errors.  The console errors are occurring because you are missing the ActionResult.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: How did you set the xml content type?The default 401 unauthorized page would not render to the xml.Did you custom 401 unauthorized page?

Comment: I didn't, that's why I'm confused here. Is there any way to manually change the content type? I also noticed, that in endpoints where I return NoContent(), the exact same thing happens.